# Multiple If-Else statement skipping the other statements

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

The problem is that I can't reach the 3rd "else if statement" where the scenario is like this:

I have 3 textboxes in HTML -> minimum value, maximum value and search keyword. if the 2 textbox has values I want to reach the 3rd if I put values in 2 textboxes, but what's happening is it's only returning to the 1st if statement.

```
 <?php
    $price_min = $_POST['price_min'];
    $price_max = $_POST['price_max'];
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ';
    
    if (!empty($price_min)) {
      $sql .='WHERE price >='.$price_min;
    } else if (!empty($price_max)) {
      $sql .='WHERE price <='.$price_max;
    } else if (!empty($price_min) && !empty($price_max)) {
      $sql .='WHERE price BETWEEN '.$price_min.' AND '.$price_max;
    } else if (!empty($keyword) && !empty($price_min)) {
      $sql .='WHERE (tags LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") AND (price >='.$price_min.')';
    } else if (!empty($keyword) && !empty($price_max)) {
      $sql .='WHERE (tags LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") AND (price <='.$price_max.')';
    } else if (!empty($keyword) && (!empty($price_min) AND !empty($price_max)) {
      $sql .='WHERE (tags LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%") AND (price BETWEEN '.$price_min.' AND '.$price_max.')';
    } else {
      echo "all are empty// ";
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`else if` is only executed if the previous `if` condition was false. A series of `if/else if` will stop at the first true condition. So this should only be used when the conditions are mutually exclusive. If both `$price_min` and `$price_max` are filled in, the first `if` will succeed, so it won't perform any of the `else if` tests. You should test for *both* being set before checking for either of them by themselves.

```
iif (!empty($price_min) && !empty($price_max)) {
    $sql .='WHERE price BETWEEN '.$price_min.' AND '.$price_max;
} else if (!empty($price_min)) {
  $sql .='WHERE price >='.$price_min;
} else if (!empty($price_max)) {
  $sql .='WHERE price <='.$price_max;
}
```

However, a much better way to do this is to just check for one variable at a time, and then collect all the `WHERE` conditions at the end.

```
$conditions = [];

if (!empty($price_min)) {
    $conditions[] = 'price >='.$conn->real_escape_string($price_min);
}
if (!empty($price_max)) {
    $conditions[] = 'price <='.$conn->real_escape_string($price_min);
}
if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $conditions[] = 'tags LIKE "%'.$conn->real_escape_string($keyword).'%"';
}

if (!empty($conditions)) {
    $sql .= 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! I think your code is way much better than mine! but how 'bout if  "price_min and price_max" has values? does "price >= $price_min AND price <= $price_max" will have the same output query as "BETWEEN min AND max"?

Comment: Yes, `a BETWEEN x AND y` is equivalent to `a >= x AND a <= y`

Comment: oh my gosh I've been stuck on this problems for days, thank you so much! can I ask one more thing if it's okay with you? I forgot to include this in my question,
I have this checkbox for category filtering and the problem is if the checkbox will only have 1 checked, the query will be "category_id = $category" but if it's 2 or more the query will be "
`category_id LIKE \'%'.$category_checked.'%\' OR category_id LIKE \'%'.$category_checked.'%\'   and so on.. depends on how many category will be checked
`

Comment: The checkboxes should be in an array. Then you can loop over all of them, and collect them into an array of `category_id LIKE "%' . $category_checked[$i] . '%"`, which you then combine using `'(' . implode(' OR ', $categories) . ')'`. Add that to your `$conditions` array.

Comment: Don't put long code in comments, it's totally unreadable. If you have other problems, post another question so you can format it properlyl

Comment: BTW, if you're putting lists in your `tags` column, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: I've moved it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63976175/10888948)

Comment: Answers should not be used to ask additional questions.

Comment: i'm so sorry, it's just my first time here. forgive me